# Is this closure in the union of the closures?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hi everyone: Suppose $V$ is an open set, and $(F_{n})$ is an increasing sequence (so $F_{n}\subset F_{n+1}$) of closed sets, all of them in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, $k\geq2$. If 
$V$ is included into the union of the interiors of the $F_{n}$'s,   can we say that the closure of $V$ is included into the union of the $F_{n}$'s?

Comment: @WillM. How does that answer the question?

Comment: I misread the question. I will delete my previous comments.

Comment: @WillM. That says nothing about the closure of $V$ though. It seems to me that $F_n = \{\tfrac{1}{n} \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq 1\}$, and $V = B^{\times}_1(0)$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Try letting $F_n$ be the closed annulus $\tfrac{1}{n} \leq \Vert x \Vert \leq 1$, and letting $V$ be the punctured unit disk $0 < \Vert x \Vert < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $V = \Bbb R^d - \{0\}$ and $\mathrm{F}_n : \|x\| \geq \frac{1}{n}.$